# Is the amount of phosphoric acid added to colas enough to disrupt the function of the kidney over the long term?

Tags: nutrition, renal-physiology

Both Coca-Cola and Pepsi add phosphoric acid $H_3PO_4$ to their colas to give them a signature "bite".

The kidneys use a phosphoric acid/dihydrogen phosphate/hydrogen phosphate homeostasis as one mechanism to eliminate/excrete excess acid from the body.

The issue of whether sodas containing phosphoric acid can exacerbate osteoporosis and related conditions has been explored [here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2139/does-pop-soda-pop-cause-osteoporosis) and in some detail on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphoric_acid#Biological_effects_on_bone_calcium_and_kidney_health), but I'm more interested in direct effects on the kidney.

I'm interested to know if the overall renal physiology is adversely affected by extra phosphoric acid that long-term moderate consumption (say a single 2L bottle per week for a year) of soda would introduce (including interrupting or saturating the [Na-Pi transporter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium/phosphate_cotransporter))?

Comment: Could you define "long-term"? Say, one 200ml can of soda/day for 10 years?

Comment: @nico That's a good idea.  I was trying to make it more abstract and less "medical advice"y.

Comment: It's just that I have the feeling that the result would vary a lot depending on the frequency of assumption (not that I have any data whatsoever regarding this issue. Very interesting nevertheless!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phosphoric acid in cola will contribute to dietary intake of phosphate. I may be missing something, but, since the transporter functions to reabsorb phosphate that has been filtered out at the glomerulus, excess phosphate will spill over into the urine.

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dietary_Reference_Intake) the RDA for phosphorus is 700 mg and the tolerable upper intake level is 4000 mg. Coca cola contains 17 mg phosphorus (as phosphate) 100 ml<sup>-1</sup> (which is 340 mg in 2 L)

According to [this source](http://www.prosebeforehos.com/image-of-the-day/10/13/cocacola-consumption-per-capita/),

> in the United States, an average person drinks 412 8-ounce drinks — or 3296 ounces — of Coke per year.

This works out at 9 oz per day = 266 ml = 45 mg phosphorus

For comparison (from [here](http://apjcn.nhri.org.tw/server/info/books-phds/books/foodfacts/html/data/data5f.html)):

- white flour contains 595 mg 100 g<sup>-1</sup>
- one boiled egg contains 220 mg
- canned salmon contains 240 mg 100 g<sup>-1</sup>

Comment: No, you didn't miss anything, great answer!  I was thinking about the precision of the acid-base balance of that particular system being disturbed (realizing, of course, that it potentially only handles "spillovers" from the bicarb system, I think).  It's interesting to see the comparison of the content with other foods, though I'd be curious about how much of that in the egg, etc., is AMP/ATP and others.

Comment: Brain fart on selecting this as the answer, sorry for the delay.